# Uploading files to Azure blob storage taking more time for larger files

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

> Hi All...
>
> I am trying to uploading the lager file (size more than 100 MB) files
>   to Azure blob storage.Below is the code.
>
> My problem is even though I have used BeginPutBlock with TPL (Task
>   Parallelism) it is taking more time (20 Min for 100 MB uploading). But
>   i have to upload the files more than 2 GB size. Can anyone please help
>   me on this.

```
namespace BlobSamples {
    public class UploadAsync
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string filePath = @"D:\Frameworks\DNCMag-Issue26-DoubleSpread.pdf";
            string filePath = @"E:\E Books\NageswaraRao Meterial\ebooks\applied_asp.net_4_in_context.pdf";
            string accountName = "{account name}";
            string accountKey = "{account key}";
            string containerName = "sampleContainer";
            string blobName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            //byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            Stream fileContent = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath);

            StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);
            CloudBlobClient blobclient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobclient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

            // Define your retry strategy: retry 5 times, starting 1 second apart
            // and adding 2 seconds to the interval each retry.
            var retryStrategy = new Incremental(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
              TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            // Define your retry policy using the retry strategy and the Azure storage
            // transient fault detection strategy.
            var retryPolicy =
              new RetryPolicy<StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);

            // Receive notifications about retries.
            retryPolicy.Retrying += (sender, arg) =>
                {
                    // Log details of the retry.
                    var msg = String.Format("Retry - Count:{0}, Delay:{1}, Exception:{2}",
                        arg.CurrentRetryCount, arg.Delay, arg.LastException);
                };

            Console.WriteLine("Upload Started" + DateTime.Now);
            ChunkedUploadStreamAsync(blob, fileContent, (1024*1024), retryPolicy);
            Console.WriteLine("Upload Ended" + DateTime.Now);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static Task PutBlockAsync(CloudBlockBlob blob, string id, Stream stream, RetryPolicy policy)
        {
            Func<Task> uploadTaskFunc = () => Task.Factory
                .FromAsync(
                    (asyncCallback, state) => blob.BeginPutBlock(id, stream, null, null, null, null, asyncCallback, state)
                    , blob.EndPutBlock
                    , null
                );
            Console.WriteLine("Uploaded " + id + DateTime.Now);
            return policy.ExecuteAsync(uploadTaskFunc);
        }

        public static Task ChunkedUploadStreamAsync(CloudBlockBlob blob, Stream source, int chunkSize, RetryPolicy policy)
        {
            var blockids = new List<string>();
            var blockid = 0;

            int count;

            // first create a list of TPL Tasks for uploading blocks asynchronously
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            var bytes = new byte[chunkSize];
            while ((count = source.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                var id = Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(++blockid));
                blockids.Add(id);
                tasks.Add(PutBlockAsync(blob, id, new MemoryStream(bytes, true), policy));
                bytes = new byte[chunkSize]; //need a new buffer to avoid overriding previous one
            }

            return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
                tasks.ToArray(),
                array =>
                {
                    // propagate exceptions and make all faulted Tasks as observed
                    Task.WaitAll(array);
                    policy.ExecuteAction(() => blob.PutBlockListAsync(blockids));
                    Console.WriteLine("Uploaded Completed " + DateTime.Now);
                });
        }
    } }
```

Comment: I noticed that you included your storage account credentials in the question. Even though I have removed them from the question but I highly recommend changing your account key immediately.

Comment: If you are doing this from your machine, your primary constraint is likely to be your available upload bandwidth. If you're on ADSL for example, your upload bandwidth is probably <0.5 Mbps, which means you can only upload ~0.05 MB per second (the rating is in bits, not bytes, so divide by 10 to get approximate speed in bytes). If you are saturating your bandwidth, increasing parallelism is likely to decrease overall throughput.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, any updates?

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept command line tool, you can try [AzCopy](http://aka.ms/azcopy), which is able to transfer Azure Storage data in high performance and its transferring can be resumed.

If you want to control the transferring jobs programmatically, please use [Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement/), which is the core of AzCopy.

Comment: I have to expose an API to upload the files using Web API

Answer (score 0):

As I known, Block blobs are made up of blocks. A block could up to 4MB in size. According to your code, you set the block size to 1MB and programatically uploaded each block in parallel. For a simple way, you could leverage the property `ParallelOperationThreadCount` to upload blob blocks in parallel as follows:

```html
//set the number of blocks that may be simultaneously uploaded
var requestOption = new BlobRequestOptions()
{
    ParallelOperationThreadCount = 5,
    //Gets or sets the maximum size of a blob in bytes that may be uploaded as a single blob
    SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes = 10 * 1024 * 1024 //maximum for 64MB,32MB by default
};

//upload a file to blob
blob.UploadFromFile("{filepath}", options: requestOption);
```

Upon the option, when your blob(file) is larger than the value in `SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes`, then the storage client breaks the file into blocks(4MB in size) automatically and upload the blocks simultaneously.

Based on your requirement, I created an ASP.NET Web API application which exposes a API to upload file to Azure Blob Storage.

Project URL: [AspDotNet-WebApi-AzureBlobFileUploadSample](https://github.com/brucechen1019/AspDotNet-WebApi-AzureBlobFileUploadSample)

**Note:**

In order to upload large file, you need to increase the `maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` in your web.config as follows:

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152"/>  <!--KB in size, 4MB by default, increase it to 2GB-->
</system.web>
```

```html
<system.webServer> 
      <security> 
          <requestFiltering> 
             <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />  <!--Byte in size,increase it to 2GB-->
          </requestFiltering> 
      </security> 
</system.webServer>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the replay, it is taking more time to upload the large file which size is 61 MB, and i have a scenario to support for uploading more than 1 GB can you help me on this....

Comment: Are you meaning that you have tested with my code,but result in a slower response? I have test this on my local side and Azure and got a acceptable result. Have you tried to test [Azure Storage Blob Upload Speed Test](http://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/Upload).

Comment: yes i have tested with your code , using my Azure Storage credentials. The response time is taking more.

Comment: I got response as BlobUploadCostInSeconds 227.05s when i upload a 60 MB file.It is showing 4 min but actually upload is taking more than that can you explain the reason. So that it would be helpful

Comment: From [AzureBlobStorageMultipartProvider](https://github.com/brucechen1019/AspDotNet-WebApi-AzureBlobFileUploadSample/blob/master/WebApi-AzureBlobFileUploadSample/WebApi-AzureBlobFileUploadSample/Utils/AzureBlobStorageMultipartProvider.cs), you could find that `BlobUploadCostInSeconds` means the cost time of `CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile`. Since the file is directly uploaded to your web api back-end, then uploaded to Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: So the total cost time for uploading files mainly is consist of the time cost when you uploading files to your web api back-end and the time cost when the files uploaded to Azure Blob Storage within your web api back-end.

Comment: Any updates? In your console test application, you created multiple tasks by `chunkSize` to upload your blocks in batch. Have you tried to increase `ParallelOperationThreadCount` in [AzureBlobStorageMultipartProvider.cs](https://github.com/brucechen1019/AspDotNet-WebApi-AzureBlobFileUploadSample/blob/master/WebApi-AzureBlobFileUploadSample/WebApi-AzureBlobFileUploadSample/Utils/AzureBlobStorageMultipartProvider.cs) to see whether it could reduce the time cost of uploading large file to Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: When I debug the API it it working very well when i deployed in azure it is taking more time to upload for 10 MB also. I didn't understand why this is happening. I have deployed the api in release mode also but icould not see any difference in speed. And i have choose central india which near to me even though upload is not happening like debug mode.

Comment: What App Service Plan pricing tier are you using? For shared or free pricing tier, you could only assign the limited resource. For troubleshooting this issue, you could [monitor apps in azure app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-monitor) or leverage [application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-azure-web-apps).

Comment: I am using Basic: 1 Small and the account is Enterprise account

Comment: I am using pricing tire( Basic: 1 Small ) and the account is Enterprise account

Comment: Have you tried to troubleshoot this performance issue by using [App Service Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-monitor)  or [application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-azure-web-apps) to collect performance metrics data? Also, have you tried to scale up your app service plan to a higher pricing tier for a better performance?

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you use [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy) when uploading large files, it saves a lot time for coding by yourself and is more efficient. For upload a single file, run the command below:

```
AzCopy /Source:C:\folder /Dest:https://youraccount.blob.core.windows.net/container /DestKey:key /Pattern:"test.txt"
```